# Why is my LSTM's prediction only provides an 1 step-out prediction, while the training is 2 step out?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

splease assist. My jupyter notebook is here: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-EY3spBWpjOh4KJxxA3GqoxvPMCWyg2D/view?usp=sharing)

I am doing a simple LSTM training. It is multivariate, 3 step-in, 2-step out, while the target column is the first column.

```
# multivariate multi-step lstm
from numpy import array
from numpy import hstack
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense

# define input sequence
target = array([100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115])
in_seq2 = array([200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215])
in_seq3 = array([target[i]+in_seq2[i] for i in range(len(target))])
# convert to [rows, columns] structure
target = target.reshape((len(target), 1))
in_seq2 = in_seq2.reshape((len(in_seq2), 1))
in_seq3 = in_seq3.reshape((len(in_seq3), 1))
# horizontally stack columns
df = hstack((target, in_seq2, in_seq3))

from numpy import array

n_steps_in, n_steps_out = 3, 2

# split a multivariate sequence into samples
def split_sequences(sequences, n_steps_in, n_steps_out):
    X, y = [], []
    for i in range(len(sequences)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps_in
        out_end_ix = end_ix + n_steps_out
        # check if we are beyond the dataset
        if out_end_ix > len(sequences):
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        seq_x, seq_y = sequences[i:end_ix, :], sequences[end_ix:out_end_ix, 0]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)

X, y = split_sequences(df, n_steps_in, n_steps_out) # (df, 3 step_in, 2 step_out)
print("X is: ", X, "\n")
print("y is: ", y, "\n")
```

return:

> X is:  [[[100 200 300]   [101 201 302]   [102 202 304]]
>
> [[101 201 302]   [102 202 304]   [103 203 306]]
>
> [[102 202 304]   [103 203 306]   [104 204 308]]
>
> [[103 203 306]   [104 204 308]   [105 205 310]]
>
> [[104 204 308]   [105 205 310]   [106 206 312]]
>
> [[105 205 310]   [106 206 312]   [107 207 314]]
>
> [[106 206 312]   [107 207 314]   [108 208 316]]
>
> [[107 207 314]   [108 208 316]   [109 209 318]]
>
> [[108 208 316]   [109 209 318]   [110 210 320]]
>
> [[109 209 318]   [110 210 320]   [111 211 322]]
>
> [[110 210 320]   [111 211 322]   [112 212 324]]
>
> [[111 211 322]   [112 212 324]   [113 213 326]]]
>
> y is:  [[103 104]  [104 105]  [105 106]  [106 107]  [107 108]  [108
> 109]  [109 110]  [110 111]  [111 112]  [112 113]  [113 114]  [114
> 115]]

they are exactly what i want. I want 3 step-in, e.g. [[111 211 322],[112 212 324],[113 213 326]] and the model forecasts 2 step-out, [[114 115]]. Then i go on splitting in train and test.

```
length = 7
train_X, train_y= X[:length, :], y[:length, :]
test_X, test_y = X[length:, :], y[length:, :]

import time
start = time.perf_counter()
print("Starting...")

# design network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]))) # time step and features
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
# fit network
history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=50, batch_size=72, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
# plot history
pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()

end = time.perf_counter()
print("Done, time spent: ", end - start)
```

so when i do the prediction,

```
# demonstrate prediction
n_steps_in, n_features = test_X.shape[1], test_X.shape[2]
x_input = array([[111, 211, 322],[112, 212, 324],[113, 213, 326]]) 
x_input = x_input.reshape((1, n_steps_in, n_features)) # sequence, n_steps_in, n_features
yhat = model.predict(x_input, verbose=0)
print(yhat)
```

yhat returns:

> [[2.321811]]

So i am wondering,
first, why is it only a one step-out answer?
second, why the number is so wrong? I put in a small epoch, and batch size, because i am actually testing something else, but still, this answer is way off, and only an 1 step-out. I am expecting something like [[114 115]].

Guys please help.

Comment: What kind of metrics did you get when you ran `model.fit`?

Comment: If you set `return_sequences=True` in `LSTM` then the model will have outputs with shape `(batch_size, 3)` in your case, how did you want model to output so it can have shape of `(batch_size, 2)` as you want? only care about last two timesteps outputs of model?

Comment: thank you Mr.For Example. I read about return_sequences, and stateful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296013/why-set-return-sequences-true-and-stateful-true-for-tf-keras-layers-lstm, i didn't set it here. And in fact the models i did didn't set it 'return_sequences=True', and they still returned a sequence. I am pretty confused here too.

Comment: @Hobbs, my model.fit metrics are: model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=50, batch_size=72, validation_data=(test_X, test_y), verbose=2, shuffle=False)